# Flutter: Retrieve data from Firestore into Dropdown menu and upload selected value back to Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating Add New Property Form for real estate app.

in the form, I would like to let user choose property type in the Dropdown Form, [like this](https://im7.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-7-b4952fc85136.gif)

and I have my database structured [like this](https://paste.pics/6aeebb3cd4fe56bf063115c0fa35edc8)

As for now, I can retrieve Property Types from Firestore and display into the Dropdown using StreamBuilder.

I would like to know if it makes sense to upload the selected (property type) value back to Firestore and save that data as part of the property model [like this](https://paste.pics/01f562af5b12c84a6d46e7a37364d9d7)

please let me know if you want to see my code.

thank you for your time and attention.

Here is my code for Add New Property Form

```
class AddNewPropertyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddNewPropertyForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddNewPropertyFormState createState() => _AddNewPropertyFormState();
}

class _AddNewPropertyFormState extends State<AddNewPropertyForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  late String _propertyid, _propertyPrice;
  String? _propertyTitle;


  final List<Map<String, String>> _propertyStatus = [
    {'name': 'For Sale'},
    {'name': 'For Rent'}
  ];

  var _selectedValue;

  void _submit() async {
    //if validation is true, then process to sumitting the form to Firestore
    try {
      final postOwnerId = context.read<firebaseAuth.User>().uid;
      final newProperty = TestNayyaaProperty(
        postOwnerid: postOwnerId,
        propertyid: _propertyid,
        propertyTitle: _propertyTitle.toString(),
        propertyPrice: _propertyPrice,
        propertyStatus: _propertyStatus.toString(),
        propertyType: _selectedValue,
      );
      await context.read<PropertyAPI>().addNewProperty(newProperty);
    } catch (e) {
      errorDialog(context, Exception(e));
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('ANP Test'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              FormBuilder(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    //Property I.D
                    FormBuilderTextField(
                      name: 'Property I.D',
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Enter Property I.D'),
                      onChanged: (val) => _propertyid = val.toString(),
                    ),

                    //Proerty Price
                    FormBuilderTextField(
                      name: 'Property Price',
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Enter Property Price'),
                      onChanged: (val) => _propertyPrice = val.toString(),
                    ),



                    //! Got only Doc ID
                    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('propertyTypes')
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Container();
                          } else {
                            List<DropdownMenuItem> typeItems = [];

                            for (int i = 0;
                                i < snapshot.data!.docs.length;
                                i++) {
                              DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                              typeItems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: Text(snap.id),
                                value: '${snap.id}',
                              ));
                            }

                            return DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                                hint: const Text('Choose Property Type'),
                                value: _selectedValue,
                                items: typeItems,
                                onChanged: (typeValue) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedValue = typeValue;
                                  });
                                });
                          }
                        }),


                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        _submit();
                        Navigator.of(context)
                            .pushNamed(NayyaaRouteManager.anppge2);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Next'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is anything not working about your current solution? If not, I'd go with it for now - unless you foresee problems already.

Comment: Hell Frank, thank you for your comment. I am still not able to upload the selected value to Firestore. I have added my code to the question. Please kindly see the code and tell me where I am going wrong with it. Thank you so much for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

```
// To get read from table
final docs = (await _firestore.collection('propertyTypes').get()).docs;
final List<String> options = [];
for (int i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
  options.add(docs[i].data()['propertyTypeName'] as String);
}

// To save data
const docId = uuid.v4();
_firestore.collection("User Post").add({
  "Post I. D.": docId,
  "PropertyPrice": 550000,
  "PropertyStatus": "For Rent",
  "PropertyType": "House"
});
```

Use https://pub.dev/packages/uuid Package for UUID